# How to check if user has restricted camera in settings of iphone

Tags: jquery, iphone, cordova

I am new to phonegap. I am developing an application using 2.7 version of it with jquery, HTML and its iOS pugin 'Torch.js'. It is used to  turn the flash light of camera ON/OFF. I found the plugin at https://github.com/tomschreck/iOS-Torch-Plugin . Whereas I want to detect if user has restricted/disabled camera in general settings of iPhone.

Is there some way around to check if camera is restricted/disabled?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Please write below code to check..

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) { //camera avaialble }
```